# Handling ListViewItem pointer over background with a default background set Windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm making ListView where the items have alternating backgrounds, which I've managed to successfully do by using a converter setting the background of a grid in the ItemTemplate. I've also created a style that removes the margins from the content:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter
            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="False"
            CheckHintBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}"
            CheckSelectingBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}"
            CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}"
            DragBackground="#879765"
            DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
            FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}"
            PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            SelectedBorderThickness="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
            SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"
            SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            SelectedPointerOverBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"
            DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
            ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            PointerOverBackgroundMargin="0"
            ContentMargin="0" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, this causes the pointer over background to disappear/hide. In Addition, I am getting a border on an item when it is selected:

[image]

My questions are: Is there way to show the pointer over colour when there is a default colour set, and how can I make the selected item show a solid block rather than a border? Any help would be much appreciated!